# Making timers to run code on expired records

Tags: php, mysql, timer

I am developing a web application (PHP/MySQL), in which I need to implement timers (record `id` expires at `expiration_date`), where expiration involves the record's `state` being updated and arbitrary code being executed as required.

I basically need a BPMN Timer event.

Options I have considered, none of which I am thrilled with:

- Cronjob calling a function in the application that just queries for and updates expired records.
- At a commonly called point in the code, call this function at a fixed interval.

How is this commonly done in PHP applications?

Comment: A cron job is pretty common for PHP applications in this case, assuming one has access to the server. What don't you like about that approach?

Comment: My main gripe with this is that I would prefer the expiration handling to be executed 'on-the-dot', as they say. I had envisaged some sort of daemonized PHP script that could keep track of records soon-to-expire and handle them.

However if there is no way to easily do this (without writing the daemon haha), I guess cron will have to do.

Comment: @Alex: A 1-minute granularity is not sufficient? Note that most expiration timers I've handled were set to whole minutes, and cronjobs get started on hh:mm:00, thus matching "on-the-dot" in most cases. (btw PHP doesn't take too well to daemonization, but it could be done)

Comment: @Piskvor I had not considered that before! Following your advice I've set the seconds part of the expiration time to 00 so the granularity problem is largely non-existent now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would also choose the cronjob option.

I would also, however, have logic in my app that knows how to deal (or ignore) expired records.  Services like cron can break, so it's nice to *NOT* have to rely upon it.

Unfortunately, DBMSs don't give us quite this sort of flexibility, and you won't want to go off and do database maintenance in the event you come across one of these "expired" records.

You're best excluding them through queries, the use of views, or simple application logic.

Comment: "DBMSs don't give us quite this sort of flexibility" - the likes of `WHERE expiration_datetime < NOW()` is not flexible enough? Either you are contradicting yourself, or I have misunderstood.

Comment: I meant as a background-type activity.  There's no automatic "expire this record at 3pm on Monday" feature in any database I've ever used - it's always been down to a query, run in-line with other tasks, or as a separate job via cron or similar.

Comment: You are both right, handling the situation where the crond is not running for any reason is an important part of using cronjobs. In my case users will notice some delay in the post-processing of expired records but it should fail gracefully thanks to exclusion.

Answer (score 3):

The following is an option which you have not considered:

You could use [MySQL Event Scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/events.html) to run a stored expiration routine within the database periodically.

Some good things about this approach:

- Platform independent, works the same way on UNIX and Windows.
- Easy to set-up. No need to explain to the user how to setup cron jobs. You just create the event together with your database schema.

Downsides:

- Not enabled by default in MySQL. Need to put `event_scheduler=on` in `my.cnf` or otherwise enable it.
- Requires MySQL 5.1 or newer if I remember correctly.

Example:

```
DROP EVENT IF EXISTS expire_event;
DELIMITER //
CREATE EVENT expire_event
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MINUTE
DO BEGIN
    DELETE FROM data WHERE time < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR);
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

The above will every minute delete any rows from *data* table which have a UNIX time stamp older than 1 hour.

Comment: Yes, this would be a good solution had I not the requirement to run arbitrary PHP code at the same time as well.

Answer (score 1):

I would choose the **cronjob** option.